# Cordova Prompt Not Working?

Tags: javascript, cordova, prompt

```
<body onload="onLoad()">

    <button onclick="onDeviceReady()">Click</button>
    <div><output id="stuff"></output></div>

    <script src="ttTracker.js"></script>
</body>



function onLoad() {

     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
     document.getElementById("stuff").value = "here";

}

 // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods

 function onDeviceReady() {

      navigator.notification.prompt("Please enter your name", onPrompt,"Registration", ["Ok", "Exit"]);
      document.getElementById("stuff").value = "harro";

 }

 function onPrompt(results) {

     alert("You selected button number " + results.buttonIndex + " and entered " + results.input1);
```

}

no prompt box will pop up when I click the button in the iphone simulator on my computer. have been working on this for a while. device ready is not working properly? please help! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put your javascript codes within `<script></script>`?

Comment: I am coding within an IDE, so the HTML and JS are in separate files.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `deviceready` listener only after `load` event has fired, by which time the `deviceready` event has fired.

Try this:

```
<body>
    <button onclick="onClickButton()">Click</button>
    <div><output id="stuff"></output></div>

    <script src="ttTracker.js"></script>

    <script>
    function onClickButton() {
        navigator.notification.prompt("Please enter your name", onPrompt,"Registration", ["Ok", "Exit"]);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {            
        document.getElementById("stuff").value = "harro";
    }
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onPrompt(results) {        
         alert("You selected button number " + results.buttonIndex + " and entered " + results.input1);
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: but then won't document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); not be run, because I am calling calling the onClickButton function. the addEventListener event is outside that function

Comment: `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` will run when the script tag is parsed at page load time. This listens for the `deviceready` event as early as possible, which will be fired when the Cordova environment is ready. Try it. It will work.

Comment: could it there be something wrong with "deviceready"? has red line under it, or is that just grammatical error?

Comment: still not working, should be running onDeviceReady, but it is not